# Server Error with the griffin.mvccontrib package in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, griffin.mvccontrib

In order to be able to translate my data annotations in my model with a resource file, I saw that many people recommend the solution offered by [jgauffin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70386/jgauffin).

However, when I follow the [localization tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/352583/Localization-in-ASP-NET-MVC-with-Griffin-MvcContri) my project cannot launch.

The problematic code is this one, which is supposed to go in the `Global.asax.cs` file:

```
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(
  new LocalizedModelValidatorProvider(stringProvider)
);
```

It says that the `LocalizedModelValidatorProvider` constructor does not take any arguments, which is also shown by other tutorials.

But when I change the line like this:

```
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(
  new LocalizedModelValidatorProvider()
);
```

I get the following error in the browser:

> Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArrayTypeMismatchException: Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.

The `griffin.mvccontrib` packages were installed with NuGet under Visual Studio 2012. Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You might find   [this link](http://ahmadflex.blogspot.com/2014/01/mvc-simple-example-for-localization.html) helpful

Here is how I did the registration in the above link:

```
ResourceStringProvider myResouceFile = new ResourceStringProvider(ModelsResources.ResourceManager);
//ModelsResources is my resource file generated class
GriffinStringsProvider griffinStringsProvider = new GriffinStringsProvider(myResouceFile);
ValidationMessageProviders.Clear();
ValidationMessageProviders.Add(griffinStringsProvider);

ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new LocalizedModelMetadataProvider(myResouceFile);
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear();
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new LocalizedModelValidatorProvider());
```

Make sure you are including the right assemblies

```
using System.Resources;
using Griffin.MvcContrib.Localization;
using Griffin.MvcContrib.Localization.ValidationMessages;
```

Also the assembly for your Resource file.